# Desabilitar una seccion de codigo en una url especifica de pagina web laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

tengo una pagina web y utilizo un layout general de blade para extenderlo a todas las paginas que lo requieran. En cierta pagina, supongamos localhost:8000/book quisiera que no se visualizara una seccion de codigo que se extiende desde el layout general, ¿Es posible hacer esto?

ej.

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Hola!</p>
</div>
```

Quisiera que no se visualizara el el codigo de arriba en la seccion localhost:8000/book

Saludos!

Comment: Agrega tu layout general y muéstranos la parte que no deseas mostrar.

Comment: Gracias, cree otro layout y use ese, me pareció más facil, sin tanto problema.

Comment: Nunca entendimos lo que querías hacer, y por cierto la respuesta que aceptaste no se ajusta a la sintaxis de Laravel.

Comment: Es facil, tienes un layout en laravel que se extiende a cualquier seccion o url en que lo quieras usar, el detalle era omitir una parte especifica de codigo en cierta URL. La respuesta de abajo establece comprobar la URL para omitir la parte de codigo que deseas.

Comment: Lo único que veo en dicha respuesta es un tag de PHP, el cual no se utiliza de esa manera en Blade, hay otra sintaxis. Además, asumiendo que entiendo lo que pretendes hacer, no debería hacerse ese tipo de comprobaciones en la vista, es muy mala práctica.

Comment: Gracias, cree otro layout y use ese, me pareció más facil, sin tanto problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los templates Blade permite usar bloques de código PHP:

```
<?php
...
?>
```

Entonces solo necesitarías recoger la URL actual y si es diferente a la que quieres usar, imprimes el fragmento de código o no lo haces en caso contrario.

Comment: Gracias, cree otro layout y use ese, me pareció más facil, sin tanto problema. Pero es una excelente solución!